# shall we start and shall we get started

Tags: differences

I was watching *Ted 2* and then Morgan said "Shall we get started?", and I was wondering what is the difference between *"Shall we start?"* and *"Shall we get started?"*

Comment: It seems it's only a matter of preference, really.

Answer (score 1):

They mean the same thing, but "get started" is a little less formal. It's the same deal as "Let's go" versus "let's get going" - the ones with "get" are a little bit less urgent.